# ОС Plan 9 (от Bell Labs)

Tags: ос, c, plan9

Случайно наткнулся в сети, на такую интересную ОС, называемый PLan 9.
Хотелось бы, узнать мнение хэшколдевцев , кто то из вас может попробовал ?
Знаю, что тема относится к руткоду, но думаю пользователи этой ОС являются именно программисты, разработчики. Поэтому здесь задал.

**PS:** слыхал, что Гугл активно пользуется этой Осью.

Само описание,вики:

http://www.plan9.bell-labs.com/wiki/plan9/plan_9_wiki/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-inferno_plan9_1/

Спасибо всем.